# Python f-string with a Variable Decimal Number Specifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, f-string

Is it possible to use Python f-string with a variable decimal number specifier?
Here is an example, but it does not work:

```
print(f'{1.23456:.2f}')    # working f-string code

number = 2
print(f'{1.23456:.' + number + 'f}')
```

Python3.7.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: `print(f"1.2345:.{number}f")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put a second set of brackets inside the first one:

```
number = 2
print(f'{1.23456:.{number}f}')
# 1.23
```